# How to repeat lines with awk?

Tags: awk, split

I have the following `file`:

```
var1    10    10,11,13
var2    10    12,20,91
var3    10    6,7
var4    11    4
```

I would like all numbers in the third field to be on separate lines, but I need the first two fields to remain identical:

```
var1    10    10
var1    10    11
var1    10    13
var2    10    12
var2    10    20
var2    10    91
var3    10    6
var3    10    7
var4    11    4
```

I tried using:

```
awk '{ split ($3, a, ","); print $1"\t"$2"\t"a[1]"\n"$1"\t"$2"\t"a[2]"\n"$1"\t"$2"\t"a[3] }' file | awk '{ if (length($3)>1) print $0 }'
```

But this is highly inefficient and it is tedious coding the `$1` and `$2` every time. If someone could please assist me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. Please note that the answers don't have to be limited to `awk`, it's just a preference because I'm most familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    n = split($3, t, ",")
    for (i=0;++i<=n;){
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, t[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `for(i=1...)

Comment: No. look carefully.